# (Java) error: constructor MinimaxThread in class MinimaxThread cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm getting an error that I really can't explain when trying to compile my Java code:

```
error: constructor MinimaxThread in class MinimaxThread cannot be applied to given types;
        MinimaxThread mmt = new MinimaxThread(board.clone(), 2, true);
                            ^
  required: no arguments
  found: MCBoard,int,boolean
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

The error makes no sense, as I have a constructor that takes an MCBoard, int, and boolean:

```
public class MinimaxThread implements Runnable {
    public MCBoard board;
    public int depth;
    public HashMap<Tuple, Integer> moveEvals;
    boolean cont = true;
    boolean verbose = false;

    public MinimaxThread(MCBoard board, int initialDepth, boolean verbose) {
        this.board = board;
        depth = initialDepth;
        moveEvals = new HashMap<Tuple, Integer>();
        for (Tuple t : board.legalMoves) {
            moveEvals.put(t, new Integer(0));
        }
        this.verbose = verbose;
    }
```

It's an overloaded constructor (there is one with just MCBoard and one with MCBoard and int), but I don't see how that would matter. Any ideas? Here's the calling code:

```
public static void testMinimax(){
    MCBoard board = new MCBoard();
    board.move(5,0);
    board.move(4,0);
    board.move(5,2);
    MinimaxThread mmt = new MinimaxThread(board.clone(), 2, true);
    mmt.run();
}
```

edit: `board.clone()` is overridden:

```
public MCBoard clone() {
    // irrelevant code removed
    return new MCBoard(gridClone, turn, legalMovesClone, moveListClone);
}
```

edit #2: Here is my git repository, for reproducibility:
https://github.com/cowpig/MagneticCave

Comment: Please post your `MCBoard` class code.

Comment: `It works fine`. On the side note you can not start thread by just calling `run()` method. You need to use `Thread`

Comment: try recompiling MinimaxThread

Comment: I recompile all the code every time. And I can't really post the entire MCBoard class-- it's over 250 lines of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Now that you've given us your github URL, we can see what [`MinimaxThread`](https://github.com/cowpig/MagneticCave/blob/master/MinimaxThread.java) really looks like - at least in the latest pushed code:

```
public class MinimaxThread extends Thread {
    public MCBoard board;
    public int depth;

}
```

Yup, I can see why the compiler would complain at that constructor call...

EDIT: Before we knew that `MCBoard.clone()` was overridden, the answer below made sense. Now, however, I can see no reason why the compiler should complain. Indeed, using the code you've given (but ignoring the actual implementation, which is irrelevant) it all compiles fine:

MinimaxThread.java:

```
public class MinimaxThread implements Runnable {
    public MinimaxThread(MCBoard board, int initialDepth, boolean verbose) {
    }

    public void run() {
    }
}
```

MCBoard.java:

```
public class MCBoard {
    public MCBoard clone() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Test.java:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MCBoard board = new MCBoard();
        MinimaxThread mmt = new MinimaxThread(board.clone(), 2, true);
    }
}
```

So I suspect you're not building the code you've presented. Try to build the code above, and if that works, see if you can figure out the difference between that and your *actual* code.

**Original answer**

Presumably the compiler "thinks" that `board.clone()` returns `Object`, because that's what's declared by `Object.clone()`. So you need to cast the result to `MCBoard`:

```
MinimaxThread mmt = new MinimaxThread((MCBoard) board.clone(), 2, true);
```

Alternatively, you could override `clone()` within `MCBoard`, declaring that it returns `MCBoard` rather than `Object`.

Comment: public MCBoard clone() {
        ....
        return new MCBoard(gridClone, turn, legalMovesClone, moveListClone);
    } ...
It is overridden already, but I will try casting it and see if that works

Comment: @mavix, what about `gridClone`?

Comment: I tried casting it and it didn't work. And yes, the clone() methods are all overridden to produce deep clones. Furthermore, the error says it got an MCBoard, int, and boolean, so it clearly doesn't think I'm passing an Object

Comment: Can't understand, why a downvote on this answer? @mavix.. If you have downvoted, then please note that, according to your original question this answer is correct. Please post some more code to get appropriate answer.

Comment: I can assure you that the code I've presented is the code I'm trying to compile... Here is a git repository if you want to try it yourself: git@github.com:cowpig/MagneticCave.git

Comment: Nope, it's not. See https://github.com/cowpig/MagneticCave/blob/master/MinimaxThread.java - there's *no* constructor declared in there.

Comment: Hahahahaha.... Oh god that's embarassing. Seems I've been editing the copy of MinimaxThread.java from my old directory before I switched workspaces... Thanks for your help Jon Skeet